# Are tree/log processing questions suitable for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I posted [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/what-is-a-suitable-workflow-for-cutting-down-trees) over at [The Great Outdoors SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) and it has received mixed opinions on its suitability for the site.

> I have many trees on my land that need to be cut down. I would like to know what suitable workflows there are for the whole process. Should I cut a tree down, cut it up into small pieces, and split the pieces to make firewood all in one step? Or should I cut many trees down and move them to a separate area to process the wood? I would like efficiency to be a high priority.
>
> NOTE: Assume the following equipment - 5x8 trailer with winch, 18" chainsaw, sledge hammer, splitting axe.

It has since been put on hold as off-topic. Would this question be suitable for this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site is about growing things in a garden ( not farm ), and of landscaping. It's not usually about the processing of things that have been grown in a garden unless you're using those plants/trees/fungi for the purposes of growing something else.  So, although there are questions about trees, it's about their growth and care.

If the question were about processing a tree in such a way as to encourage garden growth eg. burying trees in a raised bed ( hugelkultur ), then it would be on topic, as would be shredding the branches to create a tree mulch for your garden, and possibly burning wood for creating biochar.

As your question is about the workflow in reducing some trees to firewood, in my opinion, it is off topic for this site but I suspect you could reword it to be on topic.

Answer (score 4):

I think sustainability would be better, particularly if you were to phrase the question in terms of landscape management and what you want to do with the land after tree removal.  Check permaculture for some ideas.

https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Definitely cut them down and then delimb and cut into rounds the width of your fireplace.  Get them up off the ground to dry properly.  Takes a good year unless the trees you cut were already dead and standing.  Then get a log splitter if you have a lot to do.  You will love this thing!  Keep your wood covered but allow air to flow through.  A little rain or snow is no big deal.  When you split these rounds the chunks should sound like a baseball bat hitting another peice of wood.  The chunks will feel lighter, heavy is wet.  Be alert for nests in the tree and its citizens.

Comment: @stormy great answer, wrong area.  This question is about whether the question is on or off topic.